# Assign ArrayList element if int variable is equal to position in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to compare my int named iD to the index of myArrayList. If there is a match (iD = 1 and there is an element at that index), I want to assign to my string myName the value of the item at this position. To do this, I used:

```
for (int i =0; i <myArrayList.size (); i++) {
    if (iD == i) { 
      myName = myArrayList.get(i);
    }
```

But I get the error "cannot covert from MyObject to String" at this line:

```
myName = myArrayList.get(i);
```

Here is the whole code:

```
int iD = 1;
String myName;


public class MyObject 
{
  public String name;

  public  MyObject( String name) 
  {
    this.name = name;
  } 

  @Override
    public String toString()
  {
    return (name);
  }
}


ArrayList<MyObject> myArrayList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

void setup() 
{
  size(100, 60);
  myArrayList.add(new MyObject("a"));
  myArrayList.add(new MyObject("b"));
  myArrayList.add(new MyObject("c"));
  for (int i =0; i <myArrayList.size (); i++) {
    if (iD == i) { 
      myName = myArrayList.get(i);
    } 

    System.out.println(myArrayList);
    myArrayList.removeAll(myArrayList);
  }
}
```

I don't understand why I get this error since myName is a String and the ArrayList contains Strings. 
Could anyone help me to solve this ?

thanks for your help

Comment: Use a `Map` of some kind instead

Comment: Have you tried `myName = myArrayList.get(i).name;`, seems like this is what you looking for :-) Variable `myName` is of type `String`, though what you receive from `myArrayList.get(...)` is of type `MyObject`, hence you have to first get the `String` value from `MyObject`'s reference, and then assign that to `myName` variable.

Comment: `ArrayList contains Strings`: no, it contains instances of `MyObject`.

Comment: Why downvoting my question ? I have an error that I don't understand and can't find an answer of StackOverFlow so it feels legitimate to ask

Comment: You feel it's legitimate. I feel it's poor. You make a statement like _ArrayList contains Strings_ but don't back it up. The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, your arrayList contains "MyObject"s. Try calling the toString method.

`myName = myArrayList.get(i).toString();`

or

`myName = myArrayList.get(i).name`
since name is public.

Answer (score 3):

Your MyObject is not of the String datatype. You can fix this issue by doing

```
myName = myArrayList.get(i).toString();
```

Comment: He responded too quickly. I didn't see his answer. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

MyObject is an object, not a String. You need to convert it to String before you assign it to myName.

Do you have a method in there that can do that?